# Whats the right Database System for this

Tags: database, scala, nosql

For an application written in Scala I'm looking for the 'best' database system for the following requirements:

- Good support for queries like: For a node find all connected nodes, all nodes connected via another node with value 'somevalue'
- Available as a cloud service for 0$ for low volumes of data
- Good community support and documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you are trying to store a **graph** on your database.

There are graph databases especially created for storing nodes and connecting nodes with vertices (in your terms, values). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database#Graph_database_projects

I'm afraid, there are no free options offered in the cloud for free. You should buy a VPS, Amazon EC2 instance, Windows Azure instance or whatsoever to host your database. Nothing comes free these days.

Among the graph databases, my choice would be `neo4j`, it has a good support, documentation, community and it is especially designed for usage with Java (and Scala, of course). However I heard that `orientdb` and `vertexdb` are also good for that.

Comment: Personally, I would go with OrientDB.

Answer (score 2):

> Good support for queries like: For a node find all connected nodes, all nodes connected via another node with value 'somevalue'
>   Good community support and documentation

[Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org) is quite adequate if you only need to find nodes within a neighborhood, in that it supports [recursive queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-with.html).

Assuming you've an oriented graph of `nodes (id, parent_id, col)`, this allows to write:

```
with rec_nodes as (
select id,
       col,
       1 as depth
from   nodes
where  parent_id = :id
union all
select nodes.id,
       nodes.col,
       rec_nodes.depth + 1 as depth
from   nodes
join   rec_nodes on rec_nodes.parent_id = nodes.id
where  depth < :depth
)
select id
from   rec_nodes
where  col = :col;
```

The above will perform very well as long as the `:id` and `:depth` constraints are *within* the `with` statement (when not, it'll build the whole graph, and you definitely don't want that to occur).

> Available as a cloud service for 0$ for low volumes of data

Not cloud, nor $0, but [very cheap here](http://hub.org/services). (Last I checked, the basic VPS offered Postgres on a shared server. And the whole thing is run by one of the Postgres founders.)

[Be wary](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-performance/2011-05/msg00048.php) when hosting a DB in the cloud directly.