# neo4j with thousands of edges

Tags: database, database-design, graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I need a strong database to query very often with some thousands of nodes, and about 2000 edges each for each node.

Is neo4j able to manage these relationships? Do I have to find another solution?

Comment: Plain old DBs work too, if you're going only ever [querying neighboring nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317044/whats-the-right-database-system-for-this/6317348#6317348).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is no problem with Neo4j, it is running graphs with millions or billions of Nodes and Relationships.

You can easily create a PoC [Proof of Concept] by importing your graph and then run the operations on it that you're interested in.

Could you perhaps describe some more details of the domain model and the use-cases/operations?

Comment: What's a PoC? However I would use it to manage different types of friendship among users, and to calculate their mutual friends.
So each user could have some thousands of edge, and other, hundreds of thousands